# Upload File on Dropbox and retrieve uploaded file URL : Android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-sdk

I have created an application, in which I have to upload media files like image, audio etc. So I am successfully able to upload the file on dropbox but I need the url of uploaded file from dropbox in success of upload. So I can work further by using that url of file.

Please anyone have answer of my question. I want URL of uploaded file once upload is successful

Note :- I am using Dropbox sdk version 3.0.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I had a same issue and got the solution using this code below:**

```
                  try {
                       SharedLinkMetadata sharedLinkMetadata = dbxClient.sharing().createSharedLinkWithSettings(metadata.getPathDisplay());
                       System.out.println(sharedLinkMetadata.getUrl());
                   } catch (CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsErrorException ex) {
                       System.out.println(ex);
                   } catch (DbxException ex) {
                       System.out.println(ex);
                   }
```

**Note:** If you had tried the same file to make shareable using any site or web, it will give you an exception.